# Android studio can't edit library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded [this library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) and i extracted the rar into my app\libs folder.

Then I added `compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'` to my build gradle as it says, and clicked on sync.

Then I noticed that the max is set to 100 (in file DonutProgress.java).
I changed it to 5, clicked on sync again but nothing changed.
After few hours of trying I decided to completely remove the extracted folder from my app\libs and sync again to see what happens.

Surprisingly, everything was still working like library was still there.
Can someone explain me what's happening here, I have to edit it but it seems whatever I do to the library doesn't affect the app.
It seems like it's using another library from totally different folder, I don't know, I tried searching for DonutProgress on my computer but didn't find anything that seems useful.

Please help.

Comment: so another question without solution, 3rd in a row i think :/

Answer (score 1):

When you add `compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'` to your build.gradle dependencies, you are telling Gradle to go fetch this library from a repository when you build.

For most Android apps, this means that when you do a build, Gradle will go and download the library (in this case a .aar) from [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). This is good because it means you no longer need to manage the JARs (or other library files) yourself.

If you want to use a custom version of that library, then you should *not* add that dependency to your Gradle build script. Instead you should add it as either a module or a local dependency (e.g. `compile files('libs/custom_library_name.aar')`).

Comment: i can't find the .aar file, please help

Comment: If you are modifying the source and you want to use it as an AAR, you will need to generate the AAR yourself. Otherwise you can add it as a module to your project and let it compile with the rest of your app.

Comment: For the most part you should be able to just copy the source for the library into your project [as a separate module](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#SettingUpLibraryModule).

Comment: so if my library folder "CircleProgress" is in app\libs what do i type?
i mean apply plugin: 'com.android.library' is for the online libraries right? 
btw, as i said there is no .aar file in "CircleProgress"

Comment: You should move the source out of `app/lib` and put it at the same level as your `app` folder. Then in your build.gradle you would add `compile project(":CircleProgress")`

Comment: i did that like this: http://www.igreklik.com/slike/viewer.php?file=22926810383894424720.png&file_imgur=5MD3RBc.png

but got Error:(25, 0) Project with path ':CircleProgress' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: That is still one level too deep for the `CircleProgress` folder- it should be under the "MyMarks" directory.

Comment: http://www.igreklik.com/slike/viewer.php?file=13015161918485616790.png&file_imgur=rQ9dBfT.png

Still getting that error

Comment: here is the CircleProgress in case you need to see what's inside http://www.mediafire.com/download/szm3d1qud0w92kf/CircleProgress.rar